# Handling a null object in a derived class c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a base class called `BaseWeather` and every weather state derives from this base class

Now `BaseWeather` contains `public ParticleSystem _ParticleSystem;` Because most of the weather states can have 1 or more particle systems(Thunderstorm->Rain->Lighting->Tornado)

Now when it comes to the Sunny state of weather there are no particle systems because the "Sunnyness" is handled by light and fog so in my derived class `Sunny` I did this to try to remedy the fact that there is gonna be a null particle system

```c#
try{
            base.ResetEmission();
        }catch{
            if (WeatherSystem.Instance._debugState == DebugLevel.Full) {
                Debug.LogWarning ("Particle System is null at Sunny.cs line 47");
            }
        }
```

My logic here was using a try block and finding that `ResetEmission()` dosent work it will just assumes its null debug the warning and it wont affect gameplay

My question is what is the "right" way to handle this scenario

Comment: Your design breaks the Liskov substitution principle. If SunnyWeather class does not have a particle system then the particle system property should not be in the BaseWeather class. Consider creating another class that inherits from BaseWeather called ParticleWeather or something to that effect.  Then your classes that have particle systems inherit from that class (which in turn inherits BaseWeather).

Comment: Aside from my answer, I'd recommend not using exceptions as part of your logic. Exceptions should be reserved for truly exceptional situations (out of disk space, no network, missing database, etc.), not reasonably expected conditions. Even a simple null check within `base.ResetEmission` would be better.

Comment: Have you considered simply adding a `if(ParticleSystem == null) return;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right" way would be one of:

1. Create another base class, e.g. `BaseWeatherWithParticleSystem` and only inherit from that if you do in fact supply a particle system
2. Create an interface, e.g. `IWeatherParticleSystem` and implement that for the classes that need a particle system.

I'd lean to the interface approach. It makes testing easier and more clearly advertises the capabilities of the class. Mind you, you could implement both approaches, e.g.:

```
public class BaseWeather { ... }
public class BaseWeatherWithParticleSystem : BaseWeather, IWeatherParticleSystem { ... }
```

As for applying the interface to the base class or the derived class, that depends on the level of support your IDE provides for easily discovering the implemented interfaces from a class reference.

Just beware of trying to handle too much through inheritance and base classes. It's easy to program yourself into a corner trying to make everything fit into an inheritance hierarchy. I find you're often better off implementing things directly and then refactoring common code after you've got the basics set up.

As @maccettura noted in their comment, the "right" way seeks to avoid violating the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles.